# My iPhone doesn't accept the contraction "doesn't" as a correct spelling, why?

Tags: iphone, ios, spellcheck

My iPhone at some point stopped accepting "doesn't" and "Doesn't" as correct spellings. It accepts other contractions. Why is this and how can I fix it? Is there something wrong with the spell checker?

[image]

Comment: Try resetting the dictionary.  You probably corrected a correction and confused it.  Settings > general > reset > reset keyboard dictionary.

Comment: Good idea, but I have a lot of corrections in there... I don't really want to go through adding them all back. Perhaps I can just add "Doesn't" back?

Comment: I guess... is there a way to retrain the spell checker to recognize "Doesn't"?

Comment: Select "doesn't" as the correct word from the suggestions above the keyboard.  You want the far left choice in this case, I.e "doesn't" in quotes.  It may take more than once to take, and it may never get it as correctly as it did before.

Comment: In the end I reset the keyboard dictionary (and restarted the phone, this step was required, too). I think this is the second time I reset the keyboard and the problem returned. But I cannot remember... so I’m documenting it here and i’ll Find out if it works. (Notice the bad caps? That’s another problem. I did not press “shift” for “F” and I did for “i”. Something seems wrong with this keyboard.)